# Excel VBA select method of range class failed

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am trying to copy ranges of data from various worksheets into one worksheet. I have written this code:

```
Sub sub1()
For i = 1 To 3
Sheets(i).Select
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Select 'line4
Selection.Copy
Sheets(6).Select
Cells(1, i).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i
End sub
```

I get a Run-time error '1004' Select method of Range class failed on the line 4. How can it be fixed?

Comment: 1) [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) 2) [How to determine last used row/column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't `Select` a sheet you `Activate` it. But actually you [shouldn't do either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/293078) in most cases.

You can shorten your code to:

```
Sub sub1()
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 3
    With Sheets(i)
       .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Copy
    End With
    Sheets(6).Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i
End Sub
```

Note that I also declared `i`. I recommend declaring all variables, and using [Option Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) to make sure you're using the variable you think you are in all cases.

EDIT: Simoco's edit is good: Here's what I came up with:

```
Sub sub1()
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For i = 1 To 3
    With wb.Sheets(i)
        .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
        wb.Sheets(6).Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Note that I declared a Workbook variable and qualified to it. One more good practice for you!

Comment: Thanks @ simoco, I was too focused on best practices.

Comment: Now it works! Seems like the declaration of `i` was crucial. Thank you, gentlemen.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't declaring `i`. That's just a good idea. It was trying to `Select` a Sheet. Happy coding!